# Teradata : Query to find CPU utilization user level (History data)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the query to find the current CPU and IO utilization at user level

**Query**

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNAME, USERNAME, SUM(CPUTIME) AS CPU, SUM(DISKIO) AS DISKIO FROM DBC.AMPUSAGE GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

But I want to check the **history data**( date and time) of CPU/IO utilization at user level

**AccountName|UserName|CPU|DISKIO|Date/Time**

**Big Picture**

A utility will be created which will fetch data from Teradata and try to generate graphs for the same on daily basis. The report will provide all the utilization details for the whole day which will help us to plot graph. The whole utility will be schedule to run once on daily basis.

**Restrictions:**

Being developer . we are not allowed to use Teradata Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally data in AmpUsage will be historized, i.e. a daily job INSERTs the result of your query into a history table and then DELETEs all from AmpUsage.

Depending on the Account strings used there might be "account string expansion" (ASE) in place, e.g. `..._&D_&H` results in one row per AMP per user per hour like `..._131025_09` which can produce hourly usage data.

Comment: OK ..
So for my daily report , we can parse the first column .. take out the time and date .. produce the graph on daily basis ... Thanks

Comment: Any idea to which table it gets historized ?
So that we can get the data from that table directly

Comment: It's the task of the DBA do implement that. Similar is normally done for other system tables like ResUsage, LogonOff and DBQL, so you might ask your DBA which database has been created already for this purpose. I used to call it dbc_hist :-)

Comment: Thanks .. you were correct .... DBA provided me the History table .. things are automated now .. :)

Comment: @dnoeth Is there option to check current(not historical) CPU utilization of overall teradata and not user level? with the help of SQL(not Viewpoint)

Answer (score 0):

You must use PDCR (Performance Data Collection Reports) if those are configured. Just type `exec PDCRINFO.CapSystemCPUtilization(date-7,date);`

Best is to check with following query:

```
SELECT * FROM DBC.TABLESV WHERE DATABASENAME='PDCRINFO';
```

check the tablename and that is very meaningful which will explain every report by its name.